# How to rename the file

Tags: command-line, cmd

I am trying to rename the window's jpg file, but fails to do so. The file is located in the sub folder.

```
 rename %cd%\Set\1.jpg %cd%\Set\3.jpg
```

The syntax of the command is not correct.

Comment: in what for a programm language

Comment: in command prompt

Comment: Specify a tag that it's in Windows that you're wanting to do this.

Comment: @md612 added an answer, does it help or do u need sth other

Comment: The answer is not suitable to use

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the precise error message and some information about how and where `%cd%` is defined.

Comment: If `%cd%` needs to be quoted, that's probably your problem right there.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for `rename`is:

```
RENAME [Drive:][path]filename1 filename2
```

Note: the second parameter is a (new) filename *only*. No `[Drive:][path]` allowed. The `rename` command can't be used to move a file to another destination.

So for your example, change it to:

```
rename "%cd%\Set\1.jpg" "3.jpg"
```

or using relative path:

```
rename "Set\1.jpg" "3.jpg"
```

Note: it's a good habit to quote paths/filenames to avoid syntax errors with paths/filenames that contain spaces or other "bad characters".

Comment: I find it's also useful to direct people to http://ss64.com/nt/ for further reading.

Answer (score -2):

I find the answer is:

```
pushd Set & ren 1.jpg 3.jpg &  popd
```